# serialize to XML path issue

Tags: c#, path, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize my Report class info to an XML. At this point I think all of the serialize and deserialize code works, but for the initial write, I'm having trouble performing the serialize, because the XML file doesn't exist yet.

for an empty text file, i can use:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"path");
sw.Close();
```

this is my code block for the serializing. the exception `(Directory not found`) is getting thrown on the StreamWriter line. I'd like to simply add an `if(!File.Exists(xmlPath))...create empty XML`. Or maybe there is a more correct way to do this.

```
public void SerializeToXML(Report newReport)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(xmlPath);
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, newReport);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`StreamWriter(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx) constructor will create the file if it does not already exist:

> > If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.

However, it will not create any inexistent directories in your path.

> > DirectoryNotFoundException: The specified path is invalid, such as being on an unmapped drive.

To create any required directories, you can include the following code (at the beginning of your `SerializeToXML` method):

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlPath);
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you really don't have to check with `Directory.Exists()` before creating.  `CreateDirectory()`, does that for you.

Comment: @MatteKarla: Not quite… Yes, `CreateDirectory` does check whether the directory already exists, but it does not do so through an `Exists` call. The implementation it uses is, in fact, slightly slower than `Exists`.

Comment: @Douglas: Since CreateDirectory checks if it exist and the performance penalty is so tiny I consider it premature optimization, not checking improves readability. And if you had to create directories most of the times then checking for exists would give you a tiny performance penalty (checking exists and then again in CreateDirectory)

Comment: @MatteKarla: I’m not entirely convinced, but your point is valid.

Answer (score 1):

First to make sure the directory exist you can use:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\directory\subdirectory");
```

You **don't** have to check if directory already exist.

A easy way to convert public classes to XML is to use the following snippet:

```
public static string ToXml<T>(T obj)
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
   {
       var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
       xmlSer.Serialize(ms, obj);
       ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       return sr.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

Then you could just use the following code to write it to a file:

```
  var xmlString = Util.ToXml(report);
  File.WriteAllText(@"path", xmlString);
```

(this example is without error handling)

Also, in your code you forgot to close/dispose the TextWriter. I would recommend using the using-statement to handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

CreateText, and the StreamWriter, will create files if they don't exist, but they won't create directories that don't already exist for you. Is your path correct?

Try Checking with a Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlPath)).

Comment: or even better: `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlPath))` which solves the problem if the directory doesn't exist like it did in ikathegreat's case.